# How to find what interface a method is for in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, interface, overriding

I have a class implementing a number  interfaces .   Part of it looks like this:

```
class Z implements A, B, C, ... {
  @override
  public void foo( Bar b ) {
      ...
  }
```

Is there a way, preferrably a shortcut, to ask Eclipse what interface the method `foo` is from?

(Note: using Eclipse version Juno)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There should be a little up arrow in the margin next to your method override. Click on that.

I'm not sure if there's an associated keyboard shortcut.

Comment: you can define a custom shortcut for it. go to Preferences -> General -> Keys and search for `Open the Implementation in the Super Type`

Answer (score 4):

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+ <kbd>F3</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> from anywhere in the class.
Here `foo1` is from `Inter1` and `foo2` is from `Inter2`.
 [image]

Update: (for reference)

```
public class Impl implements Inter1, Inter2 {

    @Override
    public void foo() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void foo1() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}

public interface Inter1 {
    void foo1();
}

public interface Inter2 {
    void foo2();
}
```

Comment: shows me all the members, including inherited ones.  But not what interface they're implementing.  Nice tip, though.

Comment: after the return type : you can see it.

Comment: I see it in your screenshot; yet mine looks alike, without the red badly-aligned bigger-font indications.

Comment: those red fonts are added by me - just to show you, they won't be generated by eclipse.

Comment: Thanks - you were right, I was blind (the list of methods was too long :) )

Answer (score 0):

Try this, really helpfull...

Press Ctrl+f3+f3